# I can not reduce the brightness of my laptop's monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, brightness

For a while now I have not been able to reduce the brightness of my screen, and I don't know why! I've tried using the shortcuts but it doesn't work )other shortcuts work fine, like for the volume, the wifi, etc).

I have also tried doing changing the brightness manually through the Control Panel, but I can not see the brightness setting (slider) anymore!
Presently, my brightness is at the highest level, which makes it very irritating to look at my screen, especially during the night. I re-installed my laptop drivers and still nothing!

I have a ACER ASPIRE E1-531G

Something else that I noticed is that I can reduce the brightness (using shortcut) only when the computer is booting, but after logging in there is no way to do it.

what can I do to solve this ?

EDIT:
[image]
[image]

Sorry my system is in French :) 'Affichage' translates to 'Display'

Comment: Have you checked if you can still use the power management features to reduce the brightness?

Comment: I checked it, but the slider that was there to reduce the brightness does not appear

Comment: Right, so somehow your windows does not detect that your laptop is a laptop. I bet in the powermanagement settings, it doesn't tell you the actions for when on battery power either?

Comment: it does, as you can see in the first picture, even if you don't understand french, the icons speaks.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft official help document.

> Adaptive brightness is a feature in Windows that uses a light sensor to automatically adjust the display brightness to match the lighting conditions in your computer's surroundings. To use adaptive brightness, you must have light sensors installed and enabled on your computer.
>
> To determine if your laptop or computer monitor supports adaptive brightness, look for the Enable adaptive brightness setting in Power Options (mentioned in the following procedure) or check the information that came with your computer.
>
> To turn adaptive brightness on or off
>
> -Open Power Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, and then clicking Power Options.
>
> -Under any plan, click Change plan settings.
>
> -Click Change advanced power settings.
>
> -In the list, expand Display, and then expand Enable adaptive brightness.
>
> -To turn adaptive brightness on or off when your computer is running on battery power, click On battery, and then, in the list, click On or Off.
>
> -To turn adaptive brightness on or off when your computer is plugged into an outlet, click Plugged in, and then, in the list, click On or Off.
>
> -Click Apply. Click OK.

Or You can use any of the software mentioned in below website.
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/software-to-adjust-monitor-brightness-and-contrast-for-dell-studio-one-desktop/

http://adjustlaptopbrightness.en.softonic.com/

Comment: when I expand display there is no "Enable adaptive brightness" option

Comment: Oh, Then It seems it don't have the sensor or few win-7 this option is not available. try using above listed softwares

Comment: but it was working before!  I don't know what happened, and it became like that, i already tried a software which didn't work, so i'm pretty pessimist for those softwares, but as i'm desperate I'll give a try

Comment: The most probable cause might be drivers got corrupted which controls ur  display, One of my friend got the same problem solved by installing the drivers. And on Mint (linux) also he faced the same problem.

Comment: which drivers specifically ? i also tried to re-install all my drivers cause i didn't know which one was concerned, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you check for conflicts or remove old drivers using `rapr.exe`?  It may have installed without being applied if you didn't specify which device and driver through hardware manager.

Answer (score 0):

- go to the device manager
- select the display adapter
- right click on Intel graphics
- chose update driver
- select browse from my computer
- select let me pick from the device driver on my computer
- select Microsoft basic display adapter

After this restart the computer and check that brightness is changed or not.

If not then go to device manager-display adapter-this time again select intel hd graphics family like in the above set of steps. After this restart the computer and try to change the brightness.

It will solve problem in 90% cases.

Comment: I followed your procedure step by step but i don't get "microsoft basic display adapter" as an option