# Why can't I dim the brightness on my Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, asus-laptop, brightness

I am unable to dim my laptop screen or turn on/enable the Night Light.  It is always at 100% brightness, even when all slider bars move up and down.

**Symptoms:**

- Using the function keys does not dim/brighten the screen, even though the slider bar appears and moves up and down.
- Going into Settings to change the brightness manually has the same thing.  The slider bar moves, but the screen doesn't dim.
- Changing the power settings doesn't do anything.  Same thing (slider bar moves, screen stays bright).

**Things I've Tried:**

- Updating drivers (including the PNP generic/non-generic drivers a la [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/903134/i-cannot-reduce-the-brightness-of-my-laptops-screen-monitor).)
- Installing and reinstalling the ASUS Utilites driver via their "MyASUS" Windows app and [website](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-F512DA/HelpDesk_Download/).
- Changing the settings in the BIOS (it's not available in there).

**Laptop Specs:**
Running Windows 10 on an external HDD via USB.  I've corrected some problems that came with this, such as forcing it to quit thinking it's a Windows To Go version.

- ASUS Vivobook 15 (F512DA-EB51)
- 3.6 GHz AMD R Series
- 8 GB DDR4 (2400 MHz)
- AMD Radeon RX Vega 8

Comment: I assume at one point this functionality worked, what version of Windows 10 were you using when this functionality worked?  Now that it does not work what version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, it used to work.  Win10 Home, v.1803, build 17134.1006.  The deal is that I kept the HDD from my previous laptop so I wouldn't have to have Windows on my new one.  I only use it for one program that isn't Ubuntu-friendly, so I just pulled the drive and now run it via USB 3.  Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be something with your BIOS/UEFI settings.

I don't have an ASUS, but I know I can alter screen/keyboard brightness in the UEFI settings for my Dell XPS 15.

You probably know how to reach your BIOS/UEFI setting, but in case you don't, here it is.

1. Restart your laptop
2. As soon as it starts to power up, press F2 repeatedly
3. Once in your BIOS/UEFI settings, navigate to power settings and see if changing brightness for your screen/keyboard has any effect.

And this is just a guess, but there may even be a setting there (like a tick box) that is preventing changes.

Comment: Thanks, but my settings are not available in the BIOS.